# Extrude normals not working properly

Tags: extrude

When I extrude these faces along normals with `Alt+E` and select `Extrude along normals` my faces get extruded wrong, even If I select `Offset Even` the thickness of the model is wrong.

I reset all my settings and reopened Blender before trying to replicate this behaviour. It still happened.

So here's what I expect
[image: Correct Extrusion]

Heres what I´m getting
[image]

Comment: maybe first try to apply the scale of your object in Object mode (ctrl A)

Comment: Can you put that in the answer to this question? This worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have changed the scale of your object in *Object* mode, you need to apply the scale with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, otherwise you will have some stretch effects when beveling, shrink/fattening, etc.